# Nginx serves response with 200 even after calling ngx.exit()

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, lua

I am trying to serve static content from `S3`. I am using nginx and lua script for its configuration. I am new to both nginx and lua.

The task that I want to achieve is :

1. Get request URL into nginx.
2. Authenticate query params of url.
3. Serve from `S3` if parameters are valid.
4. Send error response if parameters are not valid.

My `nginx.conf` file is as follows :

```
location ~ "^/media/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$" {
     set $mediaUrl "$1/$2/$3";
     set $key "$2/$3"
     set $target http://$1.s3.amazonaws.com

     rewrite_by_lua "
         local uri = '/authenticate'
         local res = ngx.location.capture(uri, {args = { param = '/xmedia/'.. ngx.var.mediaUrl }})

         if (res.status ~= 200) then
              return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_GONE)
              end
         ";

         rewrite .* /$key break;
         proxy_pass $target;
}

location "/authenticate" {
    proxy_set_header Range "";
    proxy_set_header Content-Range "";
    set_by_lua $param "
        local params = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
        return params.param
    ";

    set $test_url http://127.0.0.1:some_port/authenticate?url=$param;
    proxy_pass $test_url;
 }
```

I my case, if authenticate returns 200, then everything works fine. But even if authenticate returns `null`, nginx returns correct file and does't give error report specified in `if` statement : `return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_GONE)`.

Am I doing something wrong? How to achieve expected behavior in efficient manner?

Thanks.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#rewrite_by_lua Note that this handler always runs after the standard HttpRewriteModule.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if HttpRewriteModule always execute before rewrite_by_lua, then how can I achieve required task?

Comment: Use http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.exec inside `rewrite_by_lua`

Comment: I tried using ngx.exec, but its trying to serve file from local system and not from s3. Can you please provide me with an example for the above context? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned on your question's comments, the HttpRewriteModule is always executed before rewrite_by_lua; **therefore** you have to put the logic on the *rewrite_by_lua* section using ***ngx.req.set_uri***, like this:

```
location ~ "^/media/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$" {
     set $mediaUrl "$1/$2/$3";
     set $key "$2/$3"
     set $target http://$1.s3.amazonaws.com

     rewrite_by_lua "
         local uri = '/authenticate'
         local res = ngx.location.capture(uri, {args = { param = '/xmedia/'.. ngx.var.mediaUrl }})
         if (res.status ~= 200) then
              ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_GONE)
         else 
            ngx.req.set_uri(string.format('/%s', ngx.var.key))
         end
    ";        
     proxy_pass $target;
    }
...
```